# opening and closing mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql

I have this python function:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
def sql_query(sql):
    try:
        con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', '', 'dbs')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql)
            results = cur.fetchall()
            return results
    except mdb.Error, e:
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

then i have loads of code that calls this function, sometime the con closes and i get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "users.py", line 431, in <module>
    orders = get_orders(user_id, mongo_user_id, address_book_list)
  File "users.py", line 343, in get_orders
    order_lines =  get_order_lines(order_id)
  File "users.py", line 288, in get_order_lines
    for item in sql_query(get_order_lines_sql):
  File "users.py", line 57, in sql_query
    if con:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'con' referenced before assignment
```

where my `get_orders` code is like:

```
def get_orders(user_id, mongo_user_id, address_book_list):
    # we just want orders that are less than 2 years old
    get_orders_sql = """SELECT order_id, state, state2, stamp, reference, comments, address_id, delivery_id, user_id FROM user_orders WHERE address_id IS NOT NULL and stamp >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and user_id='%s' ORDER BY stamp DESC"""% (user_id)
    # delivery_id - this is the shipping option the user chose.
    for items in sql_query(get_orders_sql):
        #print items
        order_id = items[0]
```

there is about 50K rows in the orders

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize `con` since let say there was error in `mdb.connect` your get error when it some how reaches `final` your `con` is still un initialized

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
def sql_query(sql):
    con='' #this should be intiated
    try:
        con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', '', 'dbs')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(sql)
            results = cur.fetchall()
            return results
    except mdb.Error, e:
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```